Nginx returning 404 for Laravel Filament static files without '/public/' prefix
I've set up a Laravel Filament project and configured Nginx following the recommendations from the Laravel documentation. However, I'm encountering an issue where Nginx responds with a 404 error for static files unless I include the '/public/' prefix in the URL.

Here's my Nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /livewire/livewire.js {
        expires off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}

docker-compose file
services:
    app:
        container_name: ec-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - laravel
            - nginxnet
            - dbnet
    web:
        container_name: ec-web
        image: nginx:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '8060:80'
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - .:/var/www/html/public
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - nginxnet
            - laravel
    db:
        container_name: ec-db
        image: mariadb:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '3307:3306'
        environment:
            MARIADB_DATABASE: laravel
            MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
        networks:
            - dbnet
            - laravel
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
    laravel:
    nginxnet:
    dbnet:

volumes:
    db_data:

When I try to access a static file like http://localhost:8060/css/filament/forms/forms.css?v=3.2.71.0, Nginx returns a 404 error. However, when I add the '/public/' prefix like http://localhost:8060/public/css/filament/forms/forms.css?v=3.2.71.0, the file loads successfully.
I've ensured that the file paths are correct and the permissions are set properly. Is there something missing in my Nginx configuration that's causing this issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Why :8060? Where does that come from?

@dbf I've included my docker-compose file as well

Hmm k, could you cd into the directory where forms.css is located and do a pwd?

inside docker I guess.. /var/www/html/public/css/filament/forms

It turns out the problem was the volume in the docker compose file.
web:
    container_name: ec-web
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - '8060:80'
    volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
        - app
    networks:
        - nginxnet
        - laravel

